# Why isn't react-router Link working (ReactJS + Redux)?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, reactjs

In my root component client.js, I have the following set up:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component={MainPage}
          path="/"
        >
            <Route
              component={HomePage}
              path="Home"
            />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

And in my return(), MainPage.js:

```
        <RaisedButton
          containerElement={<Link to={`Home`}/>}
          label="Button1"
          labelColor='#88898C'
          labelStyle={{textTransform:'intial'}}
          style={styles.signIn}
        />
```

and outside of return() of MainPage.js:

```
        export default connect(
          mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
        )(MainPage.js)
```

Lastly, in my HomePage.js,

```
return(
    <div>Hello World</div>   
)
```

and outside of return() of HomePage.js:

```
        export default connect(
          mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
        )(HomePage.js)
```

MainPage.js shows up and when I click on the , the link (URL) correctly changes to 'Home' but the HomePage.js is not being rendered (coming up, replacing the MainPage.js). Any insight or guidance on what the issue may be would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

NEW EDIT**:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component ={Login}
          path='/'
        />
        <Route
          component={App}
          path="Home"
        >
          <IndexRoute
            component={MainCard}
          />
          <Route
            component={FirstPage}
            path="/Discussion"
          />
          <Route
            component={SecondPage}
            path="/Team 1"
          />
          <Route
            component={ThirdPage}
            path="/Team 2"
          />
          <Route
            component={ThreadPage}
            path="/discussion/:id"
          />
          <Route
            component={StaticPage}
            path="/Static"
          />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Maybe MainPage and HomePage in your connect should be without `js`: like `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to replace MainPage by HomePage, there are ways

**place "Home" route on the same level**

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route component={MainPage} path="/" />
        <Route component={HomePage} path="Home" />
</Router>
```

---

**with nesting**

```
import {IndexRoute, ...} from 'react-router';

<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route component={App} path="/" >
        <IndexRoute component={MainPage} />
        <Route component={HomePage} path="Home" />
        <Route component={AnotherPage} path="Page" />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

then in App component, place `this.props.children`, it will be place for components.

---

**also you can use [named components](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#named-components)**, insted of `this.props.children`. It alows you to place more then one component per route.

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route component={App} path="/" >
        <IndexRoute components={{main:MainPage, left:LeftContent}} />
        <Route path="Home" components={{main:HomePage, left:LeftContent}}  />
        <Route path="Page"components={{main:AnotherPage}} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

then in App component, place `this.props.main and this.props.left`, it will be place for components.

Comment: Thank you but I don't seem to understand the App. Could you show how App component would look like?

Comment: I'm testing out the first method, but when the button is clicked on, it says 'Cannot read property 'props' of undefined' and my 'HomePage.js' has 
{this.props.children} and used to do just {this.props.todos} and would work, with just function mapStateToProps(state){return state}. But now I get that TypeError. What may be the problem? Would I have to individually define states in mapStateToProps like so: todos:state.todos?

Comment: examples of App component https://gist.github.com/umbertoo/9ad55cfd75b7f3432a9ba900c8af80ae

Comment: can you provide a gist, or repo.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jaewonch/e32a92f865f7368a78746564ad615bb2 Please read the comment down below. Thanks again Utro!

Comment: hey Utro, just making sure you got the link

Comment: It seems like {this.props.children} in App.js is giving the propblem. I defined it to replace with the component it is replaced it, but the error pops up. Like in the codein App.js, I would like to keep like AppFloatBar and MainCoverPhoto to be on every component but only change where {this.props.children} is defined based on what Link it is called for.

Comment: sorry my Timezone differs by yours, i guess

Comment: @JoKo because you don't have any children in App for this: "this.props.children.props.route.path" and this "this.props.children".
And App doesn't have any "this.props....", because you did'nt pass it.

Comment: How can I go about passing in the necessary 'this.props.children' so that when {this.props.children} alone in App.js renders the correct component depending on the route it is intended for. So if 'Team 2' is clicked on, it renders the 'ThirdPage' component in place of {this.props.children}. Thanks Utro

Comment: @JoKo are your routes wokring now?

Comment: Sorry but did you make an edit? Still working on the problem described in the previous comment but unfortunately still no...

Comment: i can help you tomorrow. it's **11:58** p.m. in my location. [you can find me there](https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/103538784460615680)

Comment: That'll be great! Thanks Utro. Tag me when you can help me out here. Just created an id on Discord, it's 'jaycee' #8294.

Comment: Hi Utro! I made it work but I'm not sure if I formatted it properly and didn't do it the hacky way. I added the code in the original post, marked as NEW EDIT. Also, just to clarify, in the code I provided, IndexRoute represents the container component, {App} with path="Home" in this case, correct?

Comment: IndexRoute allows you to define default component for {this.props.children}-position in App component. i.e. when you open  path="Home".

Comment: Got it. Do you mind looking into this? https://gist.github.com/jaewonch/0c52907c06fea42503c5f62bcfbbb56d

Comment: Would really appreciate it if you can. Been working on it for a few days and still haven't figured it out. Need your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Link to=`${homeUrl}`>Home</Link>
```

`to` is expecting a url. depending on your `Route` setup.

Read the docs herer: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/docs